# What is best way of reading test data from CSV file with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, csv, junit, junit5

What is best/suggested way of reading test data from CSV file with JUnit 5?

Assuming one line is one test case, one column is one parameter, number of columns is fixed and different columns can have different (basic) types: String, int, double.

An example would be:

```
public class Test{

    @Test
    // ready to use annotation that may load parameters from each line 
    public void shouldCalculateDiscount(String column1, long column2, double column3) {
        assertEquals(5, column1.length());
        assertEquals(column3, column2, 0.0001);
    }
}
```

CSV file example:

```
column1,column2,column3
a,0,0.0
abcde,1,1.01
a-b-c,999,999.0
```

Approach that uses annotations would be perfect, probably something analogical to JUnit's @ParameterizedTest.

Comment: I assume it would depend on what you are testing? You should probably go into more detail, e.g. expected inputs + expected outputs style. If you're asking how to simply read the data, just read it like how you would normally outside of JUnit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suprisingly I have found two well documented approaches that really answer my question.

**First** one is from book *Practical Unit Testing with JUnit and Mockito* by Tomek Kaczanowski.
He suggests to use the following:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ReadCSVJunitParamsTest {

    @Test
    @FileParameters(value = "classpath:financial.csv", mapper = CsvWithHeaderMapper.class)
    public void testLetterCount(String value, long letterCount) {
        assertEquals(letterCount, LetterCounter.countLetters(value));
    }
}
```

It uses [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) library. It can even test a n-fold cartesian product of parameter values "*effectively testing each possible combination.*" - see `@CombinedParameters` annotation.

**Second** approach uses combination of [@CsvSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-CsvFileSource) and @ParameterizedTest, straight from.. JUnit 5.

```
public class ReadCSVJUnitParametrized {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/financial.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
    public void testLetterCountParametrized(String value, long letterCount) {
        assertEquals(letterCount, LetterCounter.countLetters(value));
    }
}
```

The **.csv** file I used for testing:

```
value,letterCount
,0
a,1
..aa,2
.!@#$%^&*(,0
0123456789,0
abcdefghij0,10
```

**LetterCounter** class:

```
public class LetterCounter {
    public static long countLetters(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return value.chars().filter(Character::isLetter).count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV stands for comma separated values, so inherently you can just split since you know the delimiter used. If you are trying to use the test data for multiple tests, you could try:

```
List<String[]> columnValues = new ArrayList<String[]>();

@Before
public void init(){
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("myFile.csv"));
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] values = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
            columnValues.add(values);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

Then in whatever test method you are using, you can simply break down the values

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
    //set x to 1 to avoid columns
    for(int x = 1; x < columnValues.size(); x++) {
        String col1 = columnValues.get(x)[0];
        int col2 = Integer.parseInteger(columnValues.get(x)[1]);
        double col3 = Double.parseDouble(columnValues.get(x)[2]);
        double col4 = Double.parseDouble(columnValues.get(x)[3]);
        //test values here
    }
}
```

or alternatively use the specific indexes if you want specific lines tested, or even randomize it if you felt like it rather than testing all lines. You could also, as you have mentioned, use this concept similarly as parameters for tests.

Comment: That's of course an option, but I am looking for something ready-to-use and easily configurable. Don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons has a good CSV library that you can use. 
 http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Comment: Thanks - that is an option, however something better suited for unit testing must exist, maybe similar to JUnit's @ParameterizedTest.